# Why does the condition within the if-else statement never satisfy even though I enter the right string that matches the string in the list?

Tags: python, list, if-statement

Q: Take inputs from user to make a list. Again take one input from user and search it in the list and delete that element, if found. Iterate over list using for loop.

My Answer:

```
enter = list()

for user_input in range(1, 6):
    enter.append(input("Enter a name: "))

new_input = (input("Enter the name you need to find in the list: "))

for check_input in enter:
    if check_input == new_input:
        enter.remove(new_input)
    else:
        print("Item not found within the list")
    break

print(enter)
```

However, when I run the code and enter 5 random strings and then enter a string that I want to delete from the list, it never meets the 'if' condition and always shows me that the item wasn't found within the list even though I enter the exact same string as entered within the list.

Comment: Please show an example run of your code, including the input and output.

Comment: Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code.

Answer (score 2):

After the first name you check, the loop `break`s unconditionally, and further names are not checked. You need to break only if you find the item, and print "item not found" only if you've gone over the entire list:

```py
found = False
for check_input in enter:
    if check_input == new_input:
        enter.remove(new_input)
        Found = true
        break

if not found:
    print("Item not found within the list")
```

Comment: Note that the for loop is not needed. `remove()` already loops for you.

Comment: but then you should wrap `remove` inside a `try` and `except`.

Answer (score 0):

```
for check_input in enter:
    if check_input == new_input:
        enter.remove(new_input)
    else:
        print("Item not found within the list")
    break
```

This loop will only remove an item if you typed in the first item of the list and then halt. Since `remove()` already searches through the entire list, you don't need the `for` or `if` statement at all:

```
try:
    enter.remove(new_input)
except ValueError:
    print("Item not found within the list")
```